# Accessing all docs in subbcollecions

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having struggles for the last couple of days, so any help highly appreciates it.

I have an app where everyday users take photos of themself ( I set the date of that day as docId), then in UI, every day has a page ( a carousel) where users can swipe and see the photos belonging to every day.
I attached a screenshot of the Firstore database.
But having a problem reading images , tried every method.

P.s : When I set the DocId for instance: 2023-01-11 it works but it just show the photos of one day , I need to fetch all images from all days.

Method adding data to Firestore:

```
final photoToDb = db
          .collection('photos')
          .doc(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(newDate))
          .collection('Today Photos')
          .withConverter(
            fromFirestore: PhotoModel.fromFirestore,
            toFirestore: ((PhotoModel photoModel, options) =>
                photoModel.toFirestore()),
          );
      photoToDb.add(photo);
    } catch (e) {
      return ('errro');
    }
  }
```

Page where I'm trying to display images ,

```
lass SugarPhotoPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SugarPhotoPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<SugarPhotoPage> createState() => _SugarPhotoPageState();
}

class _SugarPhotoPageState extends State<SugarPhotoPage> {
  final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _photoStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('photos')
      .doc()
      .collection('Today Photos')
      .snapshots();

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('${AppData.userSelectedData}');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          stream: _photoStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return const Text('Something went wrong');
            }

            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Text("Loading");
            }

            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return SafeArea(
                child: Center(
                  child: ListView(
                    children: snapshot.data!.docs
                        .map((DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                      Map<String, dynamic> data =
                          documentSnapshot.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                      return Container(
                        height: 200,
                        width: 100,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage('${data['ImgUrl']}'),
                            fit: BoxFit.contain,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                  ),
                ),
              );
            }
            return const Text('Loading');
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that with this data structure. Firebase queries are shallow, meaning that you can't query a document together with the documents in sub collections.

In `StreamBuilder` you can get `snapshots` of either one specific document by setting :

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection(...)
  .withConverter<...>(...)
  .doc(...)
  .snapshots()
```

or multiple documents:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection(...)
  .withConverter<...>(...)
  .where(...)
  .orderBy(...)
  .limit(...)
  .snapshots()
```

In both cases, you will get the data of one or more documents, but if you need the documents in a sub collection, you need to perform another query. For example if you have one document in `doc` variable, and you need data in its `Today Photos` sub collection, you need another stream:

```
doc.collection('Today Photos')
  .withConverter<...>(...)
  .snapshots()
```

So with the current data structure you can query into a `StreamBuilder` all documents in the user's `photos` collection, but the contents of `Today Photos` sub collection must be queried separately for each retrieved document of `photos` collection.

The other option is to change your data structure. You can add the daily photos to the `photos` collection, let Firebase assign an id to them and add the date as a field. This way you can have one stream for the photos, order them by date, add a limit etc.

Comment: Thanks Peter , for taking time to reply . Correct ! This data structure is wrong . Initially I tried the second solution you mentioned ,adding createTime field , but as it needed format them (firebase date format is an integer.  I moved to this solution but a not the best one . How about adding the images urls as a List

Comment: You can convert between Firebase timestamp and Dart DateTime. Adding urls as a list can be problematic if you have hundreds of urls, you can't efficiently search and sort values.

Comment: You right . Really appreciate the answer